# Debian 9 upgrade cron Error: bad minute;

Tags: debian, cron, crontab, debian-stretch

Debian stretch 9.4
Recently updated from 9.x can't remember the exact previous version
I noticed that cron is complaining about this `/etc/cron.d/sync` crontab file

```
Mar 15 10:35:00 yop cron[26343]: Error: bad minute; while reading /etc/cron.d/sync
Mar 15 10:35:00 yop cron[26343]: (*system*sync) ERROR (Syntax error, this crontab file will be ignored)
```

This cron is triggering sync and fstrim, the thing is I don't know where does it come from ?
Is it from Debian directly install?
Also I'm not sure to understand where the issue is, I was thinking about the dash `-` at the begging of the line but it seems valid in crontab.

```
$ cat -v /etc/cron.d/sync
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

5 * * * * root sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
-5 23 * * * root fstrim /
```

> If the UID of the owner is 0 (root), the first character of a crontab
>   entry can be "-" character. This will prevent cron from writing a
>   syslog message about the command being executed.

[crontab manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html)

Here is what I checked to try to understand how it has been installed:

```
$ dpkg-query -S /etc/cron.d/sync
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /etc/cron.d/sync

$ readlink -f /etc/cron.d/sync
/etc/cron.d/sync

$ cat /etc/debian_version
9.4
```

Thanks for any input